# unable to call jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack, aurelia

Probably this is a total beginner question.

I am unable to call jQuery from within an aurelia model. I'm using the JavaScript Services SPA template. Any call to jQuery fails. I tried different approaches to fix this, but was unable to get it to work.

following are the related files :

webpack.config.js

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');

var bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
module.exports = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
    entry: { 'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack' }, // Note: The aurelia-webpack-plugin will add your app's modules to this bundle automatically
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
        publicPath: '/dist',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts-loader', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) }),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
        new AureliaWebpackPlugin({
            root: path.resolve('./'),
            src: path.resolve('./ClientApp'),
            baseUrl: '/'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
};
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'aurelia-event-aggregator',
            'aurelia-fetch-client',
            'aurelia-framework',
            'aurelia-history-browser',
            'aurelia-logging-console',
            'aurelia-pal-browser',
            'aurelia-polyfills',
            'aurelia-route-recognizer',
            'aurelia-router',
            'aurelia-templating-binding',
            'aurelia-templating-resources',
            'aurelia-templating-router',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'jquery'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```

and the TypeScript model

```
import { $, jQuery} from 'jquery';

export class Home {
    private a: jQuery;

    attached() {
        alert("begin");
        this.a = $("body");  // this line fails
        alert("end");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try importing it like `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Answer (score 3):

The comment from Kelly did the trick:

> Try importing it like `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: It did not work for me. I got error "Unable to get property 'jquery' of undefined or null reference".